# webpack - how do these import statements differ?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

Assuming the use of webpack 2, and typescript, what exactly is the difference between these statements.

```
import "moment";
import "imports-loader?window=>this!moment";
import "script-loader!moment";
import * as moment from "moment";
import { moment } from "moment";
```

In the case of `webpack 2` what happens exactly...
Despite trawling through the (IMHO bad) documentation, it's not very clear to me.

I have found, for example, that using the `script-loader` seems to make some libraries available to other libraries imported with the `script-loader` but **does not** put it into global scope for other ES6 imported libraries.

for reference: my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "wwwroot/lib", "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three forms:

```
import "moment";
import * as moment from "moment";
import { moment } from "moment";
```

- `import "moment";`

Imports a file for side effects.

- `import * as moment from "moment";`

Imports a full module into the file as named `moment`

- `import { moment } from "moment";`

Imports the *named* export `moment` from the module `moment`.

## More

Read up on ES6 imports / module syntax

## Webpack

Webpack also allows you to use loaders in import e.g.

```
import "imports-loader?window=>this!moment";
import "script-loader!moment";
```

These are covered in individual loader docs e.g. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader

Comment: thanks, you missed one, which is just `import "moment"` - does that do the same thing as the script loader?

Comment: I've seperated out the webpack specific stuff 